# Symmetric Group $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I just wanted to make sure I am thinking about this correctly.
I would like to take the product $(123)(231)$.
Here, $2-3-1,3-1-2,1-2-3 \Rightarrow (123)(231)=(132)$.

Comment: The first part is correct, but you conclude the wrong permutation from it.

Comment: There are different conventions around as to how to denote and interpret permutations. The way I do it, your product takes 1 to 2, then 2 to 3, so it winds up taking 1 to 3 --- but the answer you give takes 1 to 2. So, either you are doing it differently, or you are doing it wrong.

Comment: You calculated the composition correctly, but the cycle presentation is off. You got that the composition maps $2$ to $1$, $1$ to $3$, and $3$ to $2$, so it is the cycle $(132)$ (or the cycle $(213)$, whichever way of writing you prefer - they are the same permutation).

Comment: Where are you getting $(123)$ from? According to your own work, $2$ goes to $1$, $3$ goes to $2$, and $1$ goes to $3$. What permutation is that?

Comment: Thanks. I was having a brain fart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. As you've shown, the permutation $(1\ 2\ 3)(3\ 2\ 1)$ takes $1$ to $3$, takes $3$ to $2$, and takes $2$ to $1$ which is exactly what the permutation $(1\ 3\ 2)$ does, so $(1\ 2\ 3)(3\ 2\ 1) = (1\ 3\ 2)$.

Answer (score 0):

In general a nice way of checking your work is by creating a diagram like so:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Notice that you create the matrices from left to right. After you've done this follow the path down from top to bottom like so:
$$
1 \to 2 \to 3 \text{ so the resulting permutation has } 1 \to 3 \\
2 \to 3 \to 1 \text{ so the resulting permutation has } 2 \to 1 \\
3 \to 1 \to 2 \text{ so the resulting permutation has } 3 \to 2
$$
thus we get their product to be $(132)$, exactly what you got.

Hope this method helps you in the future as it's helped me!